# How to access (previous or next) element and compare values in django template

Tags: python, django

I was working with a django app that built under a machine learning model and its pulling data from a joblib dump file.
Everything was fine but I am getting error while accessing previous element in the template for loop.
[image]

My views.py written as-
[image]

Is there any way to access previous index and compare values for this particular problem?
Please let me know.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't access indexes like python lists on Django Template Language. You can access the specified indexes such as `data.0` or `data.1`. For more complex cases, you need to write a custom template filter.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/